# Time Limit When Solving this problem in C

Tags: c, performance

**Upper Lower**

Bibi also wants to challenge Jojo and Lili. She has a string S with N as its length. The string can contain
uppercase and lowercase characters. Then she will do an iteration from the start of the string, if the K-th
character is an uppercase character, then she will change all the characters after it, such that uppercase
character will become lowercase and lowercase character will become uppercase. After the end of the
iteration, she will ask Jojo and Lili what is the string.

**Format Input**

1.The first line of the input will contain an integer T, the number of test cases.

2.Each test case will contain a string S and an integer N as its length.

**Format Output**

For each test case, print "Case #X: " (X starts with 1). Then on the same line, print the string after the
iteration.

**Constraints**

1 <= T <= 10

1 <= N <= 100000

The string will only consist of uppercase and lowercase characters.

This is my solution. But it keeps getting TLE.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
int room,len;

scanf("%d",&room);
char words[100000];

for(int i = 0; i<room; i++){
    scanf("%s %d",words,&len);
    char next[100000];
    int j = 0;

    printf("Case #%d: ",i+1);
    while(j<len){
        int k = j+1;
        if(isupper(words[j])){
            while(k<len){
                if(isupper(words[k])){
                    words[k] = tolower(words[k]);
                }else{
                    words[k] = toupper(words[k]);
                }
                k++;
            }
        }
        //printf("%c",words[j]);
        j++;
    }
    printf("%s",words);
    printf("\n");

}

return 0;
}
```

Need help for better solution.

I think the TLE comes from nested loops, but I can't figure it out without nested loops.

Comment: `for()` loops are your friend...

Comment: I tried it with for() loops, still same as using while loops, keeps getting TLE. 
Thank you for your response.

Comment: You need an extra 1 length for the string's nul terminator, and you probably need a better algorithm. The time limit is the real challenge in such questions.That's the problem you have to solve.

Comment: Before optimizing it, you should make sure it works properly. It doesn't. When I try your code, I get only lowercase output.

Comment: You have not tested this the way it runs on the teacher's machine.  The input data does not actually have a N value.  You already know it, it is strlen(words).  What goes wrong is pretty bad, the *len* variable contains a random (and usually very large) value.  And you'll write to the words array out-of-bounds, possibly corrupting the *room* variable.  My crystal ball guesses that you added the *next* variable to prevent a hard crash.  *Never ignore the return value of scanf()*

Comment: What does TLE mean?

Comment: TLE is a jargon word in online coding competitions (Time Limit Exceeded). It means "your code is too slow, look for a faster algorithm".

Comment: Am I reading this algorithm wrong? It seems like you get a string, interate through looking for an UC letter, change it to LC, then flip all the others after, *then do the same thing to the new string*. Wouldn't this have the effect of setting the whole string to lower case? Am I misreading it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "new algorithm" department -  you've implemented the algorithm as stated. However, that means you're spending a lot of time (the majority of the time, I'll guess) looping through the string, changing the case of characters, potentially multiple times. You don't actually need to do this. Keep a counter of the number of uppercase characters you've found, initially set to zero. When you examine a character, check the counter. If the counter is odd (i.e. `if (counter & 1)...`), reverse the case of the character you're currently looking at (change upper to lower, lower to upper). Having done that, test to see if the character you're currently looking at is uppercase (it may have just changed to that). If so, increment the counter. Then proceed to the next character.

This can be done in-place and in a single pass, without any nested loops.

So your loop over the string looks something like

```
for (i = 0, counter = 0 ; i < strlen(string) ; ++i)
  {
  if (counter & 1)                     /* if counter is odd */
    if (isupper(string[i]))            /* if character [i] is upper case */
      string[i] = tolower(string[i]);  /* convert character [i] to lower case */
    else
      string[i] = toupper(string[i]);  /* convert character [i] to upper case */

  if(isupper(string[i]))               /* if character [i] is now upper case */
    counter += 1;                      /* increment the counter */
  }
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Upvoted, though giving the actual code seems excessive for a question which involves homework-like learning challenges.

Comment: I really like the `strlen()` part.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with some pointers magic. Also, try to separate your program into functions, so each part of your code has a clear purpose. Finally, `scanf` is not a very good solution to get user input: if user enters more characters than expected, it can break your program (or your system if you use Windows). I've just used this `scan_str` as an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Helper function to swap a character case */
char swap_case(char c) {
    if(isupper(c))
        return tolower(c);

    return toupper(c);
}

/* Our iteration test case */
char*test_iterate(char*str) {
    char *p, *p0;

    /* Don't swap until first upper char is found */
    int swap = 0;

    /*
     * - Initialize both pointers to beginning of string
     * - Iterate until a 0 is found (end of string)
     * - Each iteration, "advance" pointer by one
     */
    for(p0 = p = str; *p != 0; p++) {

        /* If is upper, begin to swap case */
        if(isupper(*p))
            swap = 1;

        *p = swap ? swap_case(*p) : *p;
    }

    /* Return pointer to begining of word */
    return p0;
}

/*
 * `scanf("%s", &word)` is not good if you are serious and want to avoid memory overflow
 */
char*scan_str() {
    /* Lets begin with 10 bytes allocated */
    size_t buf_size = 10;
    char c, *word = (char*) malloc(buf_size);
    int length = 0;

    /* Iterate reading characters from `stdin` until ENTER is found */
    while( (c = getc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF ) {

        /* If we need more than already allocated, allocate more (10 bytes more) */
        if((length + 1) >= buf_size) {
            buf_size += 10;
            word = realloc(word, buf_size);
            if(word == NULL)
                return "Some weird error.";
        }

        /* Save read char to our word/buffer */
        word[length] = c;
        length++;
    }

    /* Add word ending character */
    word[length] = 0;

    return word;
}

int main(void) {
    int room;

    /* Two dimensional array: list of string pointers */
    char**tests;

    /*
     * Use `scanf` to read an integer
     * It's still not good enough, as you need this weird `%*c` to discard ENTER inputs
     */
    printf("Insert number of tests to do:\n");
    scanf("%d%*c", &room);

    /* Allocate memory for `tests`: array of pointers to strings */
    tests = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * room);

    /* Get input from user */
    for(int i = 0; i < room; i++) {
        printf("Insert test case #%d:\n", i + 1);
        tests[i] = scan_str();
    }

    /* Print results and free each test memory */
    for(int i = 0; i < room; i++) {
        printf("Case #%d: %s\n", i + 1, test_iterate(tests[i]) );
        free(tests[i]);
    }

    /* Free `tests` array */
    free(tests);

    return 0;
}
```